# PMD XPath rule that finds methods that use a class field whose name is not known ahead of time

Tags: xpath, pmd

I have a requirement to look for JPA persistent classes that use the JPA ID attribute in its equals() method. For example, the following class would trigger a PMD rule violation:

```
@Entity
public class Foo
{
   @Id
   private long id;

   public boolean equals(Object o)
   {
      if (o.getClass().equals(Foo.class)) {
         Foo other = (Foo) o;
         return o.id == id;
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

I know how to get the various pieces of this query to work, but not how to put it together. So, for instance, I know how to find a JPA persistent class (assuming the use of JPA annotations):

```
//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration/../Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name[@Image='Entity']
```

I know how to find the declaration of a field annotated with the JPA ID annotation:

```
//FieldDeclaration[../Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name[@Image='Id']]
```

Likewise, I can find an expression in the equals() method that references a field named 'id':

```
//MethodDeclaration[
  ./MethodDeclarator[@Image='equals'] and
  ./MethodDeclarator/FormalParameters[1]/FormalParameter/Type/ReferenceType/ClassOrInterfaceType[@Image='Object']
]
/Block//PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image='id']
```

The trouble I'm having is using the expression to find the name of the field marked with the @Id annotation, and using it in the predicate to find the line in the equals() method that uses that field.

Here's my best guess at a query, but it returns no nodes:

```
//MethodDeclaration[
  ./MethodDeclarator[@Image='equals'] 
  and
  //MethodDeclarator[count(./FormalParameters)=1]
  and
  ./MethodDeclarator/FormalParameters[1]/FormalParameter/Type/ReferenceType/ClassOrInterfaceType[@Image='Object']
]
/Block//PrimaryExpression/Name[
  @Image=ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration//FieldDeclaration[
  ../Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name/@Image='Id']/VariableDeclarator/VariableDeclaratorId/@Image
]
```

The first 7 lines returns all MethodDeclarations that have the name "equals", and takes a single "Object" argument.

The next section selects any PrimaryExpressions inside that method whose Name is equal to the name of a field that is annotated with the "Id" annotation.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have figured it out... here is the solution I came up with:

```
//MethodDeclaration[
  MethodDeclarator[
    count(FormalParameters/FormalParameter)=1 and
    @Image='equals' and
    FormalParameters/FormalParameter[1]/Type/ReferenceType/ClassOrInterfaceType[@Image='Object']
  ]
]
/Block//PrimaryExpression[
  PrimaryPrefix/@Image=
    ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration//FieldDeclaration[
      ../Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name/@Image='Id'
    ] /VariableDeclarator/VariableDeclaratorId/@Image
  or
  PrimarySuffix/@Image=
    ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration//FieldDeclaration[
      ../Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name/@Image='Id'
    ] /VariableDeclarator/VariableDeclaratorId/@Image
]
```

It seems to work.